# How to enable HttpClient wire logging in a Spring Boot 2.0.5 application?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Spring Boot 2.0.5 command-line application with mostly default configurations.

How can I enable HTTPClient wire-logging?

I tried throwing this into a `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%c] %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```

I tried adding `spring-boot-starter-logging` to the `pom.xml`.

I also tried adding JVM parameters to the app launch:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```

But nothing works. No httpclient logs at all.

How can I get some httpclient logs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution was counter-intuitive. Add this line to `application.properties`:

> logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG

Comment: Anyone out there besides myself tried this and it did not work for them?

Comment: I even tried logging.level.jdk.httpclient.HttpClient=DEBUG but nothing...

Comment: YML version `logging.level.org.apache.http: DEBUG` but fair warning, this generates a LOT of useless logging. It also doesn't translate the response body to something human readable before writing it.

Comment: Seems like when I start up the app the first time, I don't get the http traces. If I stop and restart, then it happens.  No idea why